# Unable to put a .txt -file to the end of another .txt -file

Tags: bash, concatenation

How can I put .Txt file A at the end of .Txt file B in terminal without opening the files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean without opening them in an editor? Use `cat`:

```
cat A >> B
```

The `>>` redirects the output of the `cat` command (which output file `A`) to the file `B`. But instead of overwriting contents of `B`, it appends to it. If you use a single `>`, it will instead overwrite any previous content in `B`.

Answer (score 8):

```
cat A >> B
```

Should do it. Not sure what you mean by "not opening", of course the files must be opened, in the operating system sense of the word, for this to happen.

The double arrow is "append".

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "opening the files", but

`$ cat a.txt >> b.txt`

should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

Isn't it trivial?

```
cat A >> B
```

Comment: If it was trivial, the question wouldn't be asked.

Comment: -1. We're here to answer questions and help people, not cast aspersions. Get the chip off your shoulder.

Comment: Who has the chip on their shoulder?